# Observe if terminals on a PCB became connected. Know nothing about the PCB, except it is powered with the same power supply transformer

Tags: ground, opto-isolator, ground-loop

I have a PCB with terminals I have access to, otherwise it's an unknown. I want to observe with my microcontroller (uC) if they become (dis)connected.

The PCB is powered by a 24 VAC transformer, the same powers my uC. I have build a rectifier for my uC, so they have different ones.

On the PCB's terminals, I measure 34 V when open.

There is also another kind of terminals, *command* terminals, those I can control (make them connect) with my uC. I plan to use an optocoupler for that.

But for *observing* the terminals, I cannot use an optocoupler, as surely it's not possible to drive a diode with them, right? EDIT: I measured 3.85 mA when shorted the terminals.

I could use a transistor, but then I would have to have a common ground between the PCB and my uC.

I believe there are two possible situations: 1) the rectifiers are in sync (I could connect the terminal I observe \$\text{0 V}\$ relative to my uC ground, or will I even observe that?), or 2) they are shifted in phase by \$\pi\$, so I would just switch the wires that lead to *my* rectifier.

Is it safe to connect uC ground with *a* terminal, if by multimeter I measure 0 V? I don't know if there are resistors or other components on the PCB in the way and if that even would be a problem.

If this common ground method isn't safe (and it'd better be, I cannot destroy the PCB, not cheap), is there another way to observe the (dis)connected state of terminals? (A mosfet operating a battery driven optocoupler, in case connecting a battery lead to a terminal is safer.)

---

Additional information (may not be relevant):

The terminals to observe are normally closed

Description for the image:

\$\text{COM60, IC 1, IC 2}\$ are *command* terminals, \$\text{COM60}\$ is common for the others, if \$\text{IC 1}\$ or \$\text{IC 2}\$ become connected with \$\text{COM60}\$, a command is issued to the PCB. These I plan to control with an optocoupler.

\$\text{COM70, SAFE1}\$ are the terminals I want to observe if they become (dis)connected. Actually there's a third device that taps into those terminals (probably a photoresistor), but it has to be connected to the PCB the way it is.

Between the common and the others, in open state, I measure 34 V (common being positive).

[image: Terminals]

Comment: I'm still confused what "if they become connected" means: is there something on the PCB that you know that shorts these two contacts?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, into the same terminals a safety photocell is connected (not exactly on the PCB). It opens the contacts if something breaks an ir beam.

Comment: So basically I want to observe the photocell, but it still has to be connected to the PCB as is.

Comment: @Adam describe the connectors on the PCB (or show a schematic), can these be changed? Can you add to signals to the connector or a new connector?

Comment: @VoltageSpike no, I cannot make any modifications to the PCB. All I can do is to connect wires to those terminals.

Comment: @Adam what terminals? Please provide information on the terminals a schematic would be useful

Comment: @VoltageSpike I added the scheme of the PCB's terminals

Comment: @Adam, that's great, but I can't see anything related to an external PCB or a connector. What are JP7 and JP8?

Comment: @VoltageSpike All I want to do, is to observe if terminals no. 70 and 72 become disconnected.
In the picture, there is the PCB. My uC is not shown, as I don't know how to connect it. I provided the power supply details in the question.

Comment: @Adam What power supply? Keep in mind I know nothing about your design, you need to modify your question so that I could know everything I need to know about your problem without explanation. Imagine you are writing a letter and you only get one chance for a response, what info would you put in the letter to ask for help on this design? What would they need to know? We don't know what you know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108890/discussion-between-voltage-spike-and-adam).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The PCB is powered by a 24 VAC transformer, the same powers my uC. I have build a rectifier for my uC, so they have different ones.

You have to be very careful here. If the PCB has a full-wave (bridge) rectifier and your microcontroller has one then the PCB ground and the micro ground are not directly connected. Opto or relay isolation would be a very good idea.

> On the terminals, I measure 34 V when open.

Unusual, but OK.

> But for observing the terminals, I for cannot use an optocoupler, as surely it's not possible to drive a diode with them, right? They must have some high ohm resistors beside them, so when connected, there isn't a short.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0DYrb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) What you've got. (b) A simple solution if ...*

Switch your multimeter to mA and measure the current by connecting 60 to 61 or 62. If the current is between, say 5 to 20 mA then you can use the circuit of Figure 1b. This allows you to monitor the status of IC1 and IC2 with complete isolation.

If the current is not between 5 and 20 mA then update your question with the additional information.

> I believe there are two possible situations: 1) the rectifiers are in sync (I could connect the terminal I observe 0 V relative to my uC ground, or will I even observe that?), or 2) they are shifted in phase by π, so I would just switch the wires that lead to my rectifier.

Try to avoid connecting the systems together since you don't know the rectifier arrangement.

---

From the comments:

> I measured 3.85 mA directly between 70 and 72 contacts.

That should be enough for an opto-isolator.

> I would prefer, if the optocoupler was parallel to the switches. ... If the switch was disconnected, more current would flow through the optocoupler circuit, than the switch circuit (none), charging a capacitor and then letting out pulses for the LED.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frcfdF.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. Your idea won't work. There will be almost no difference in the current to your PCB if the switch is open or closed.*

The voltage will decrease by about 1.4 V (because of the infrared LED) so the current could be expected to drop by 1.4/34 = 4%. The PCB will think the switches are always closed.

Comment: I measured 3.85 mA directly between 70 and 72 contacts. I took the safety photocell's wires completely from the terminals, as I didn't want to have them connected not as intended. Depending on the internals of the safety photocells, it may a transistor, or just a photoresistor adding some resistance.

Comment: I would prefer, if the optocoupler was parallel to the switches. Also if it would shine if the contacs became disconnected (almost never). 
Due to the low measured current, wouldn't it be possible to connect the optocoupler circuit in parallel to the switch? -- If the switch was disconnected, more current would flow through the optocoupler circuit, than the switch circuit (none), charging a capacitor and then letting out pulses for the LED

Comment: See the update.

Comment: Perfect. I hope that connecting the switch in series will not limit the current much (not knowing the type of the switch). 
My idea could only work if I managed to slowly charge a cap for a pulse of the LED, right? But hope this works, as it's much simpler.